# Gatling report doesn't have details for KO

Tags: scala, performance-testing, gatling, scala-gatling

I faced this issue while running all tests together. It says 11 KOs but there is no detail about the KOs in the list. I could not get which requests causing this issue. I also checked the log from the machine but it says all test passing.

[image]

This one of the machine logs, I run these tests in 3 machines but all the same.

```
================================================================================
---- Global Information --------------------------------------------------------
> request count                                       1142 (OK=1142   KO=0     )
> min response time                                     54 (OK=54     KO=-     )
> max response time                                   1426 (OK=1426   KO=-     )
> mean response time                                   186 (OK=186    KO=-     )
> std deviation                                        170 (OK=170    KO=-     )
> response time 50th percentile                        116 (OK=116    KO=-     )
> response time 75th percentile                        271 (OK=271    KO=-     )
> response time 95th percentile                        461 (OK=461    KO=-     )
> response time 99th percentile                        782 (OK=782    KO=-     )
> mean requests/sec                                 12.413 (OK=12.413 KO=-     )
---- Response Time Distribution ------------------------------------------------
> t < 800 ms                                          1132 ( 99%)
> 800 ms < t < 1200 ms                                   7 (  1%)
> t > 1200 ms                                            3 (  0%)
> failed                                                 0 (  0%)
================================================================================
```

Comment: First, make sure you're using the latest version and not an old possibly buggy one. Then, if you still experience an issue after upgrading, please provide yoru simulation.log file.

Comment: @StéphaneLANDELLE I am using 3.3.1, let me update it to 3.6.0